# Testing trend terms in time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I have some time series data I believe has non negative trend. I have been trying to test this assumption in R using a t-test, with the idea that if the trend value is negative and the P-value significant, I can reject my hypothesis.

Is a t-test a correct approach with time series data? I have been reading some things about Dickey-Fuller tests but don't really understand the use/differences. When would I use a Dickey-Fuller test to test trends?

Are there any other more standard approaches with packages in R when trying to determine the trend of a time series and whether the trend is significant, assuming normal errors and constant variance, without necessarily knowing if the model is ARIMA(p,i,q)?